# Request body validation in Spring boot application Fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I want my REST API to throw an exception whenever there exist and parameter type mismatch. Following is my request object.

```
public class MyReqDto {
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", message = "Invalid characters found in subscriberType")
    private String subscriberType;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]", message = "Invalid characters found in caseId")
    private String caseId;
```

In above case en exception should be thrown whenever a request violate this String requirement (Providing an integer value to subscriberType). Also I need to validate them against invalid characters such as *,-,<,> etc. For this I have used @Pattern annotation.

My controller looks like this.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/my-controller/traceId/{Trace_ID}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces =
            "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> startWork(@PathVariable Optional<String> Trace_ID,
                @Valid @RequestBody MyReqDto myReqDto)
            throws Exception {
```

I am using @Valid annotation and I have included maven dependency for **hibernate-validator**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

But the problem is, it does not validate my input and accept integer values for subscriberType and caseId.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the accepted set of characters? It is not very clear

Comment: Your regex accepting digits.

Comment: Hi guys , these paramters can have combination of numbers and characters but not symbols like *,-,>,<,# etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure with acceptance criteria. I assume you are expecting like following patterns.

**Regex Patterns**

- `[A-Za-z ]*` to match letters and spaces.
- `".*[^0-9].*"` to match Numbers

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regex pattern seems OK. However my problem exists in validating them through request body.

Comment: I think the problem is within the regex, the annotations seem correct to me

Answer (score 0):

The issue in validating pattern was in my regex. Following solved the problem.

```
public class MyReqDto {
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]", message = "Invalid characters found in subscriberType")
    private String subscriberType;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]", message = "Invalid characters found in caseId")
    private String caseId;
```

I noticed that by default declaring a request body parameter as string, and providing it with a integer value works fine, no exceptions thrown. However if we declare a request body parameter as integer and provide it with a string value, it will throw an exception.

Simply caseId="123" and caseId=123 have same effect in my request body since caseId is declared as a string.